# using antlr4 C# grammar in java

Tags: java, c#, antlr4, parse-tree

How can I obtain the parse tree of a C# file using C# grammar and antlr 4 in java?
I have tried to generate a parser and lexer for C# grammar, but is generated only the parser, and it throws this error:

> can't find or load grammar CSharp4PreProcessor

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the grammar from this [link](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/csharp), you will have to download all the .g4 files there.